# clicking on sitemap should load category page and show description at top - NopCommece

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-routing, nopcommerce

I am adding description for categories and sub categories and a conditional css in the  `<div class="category-description" (I want to add condition here for conditional css to make display block or none)>` in `CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml` page by default making the description block to hide when any user clicks on products tab directly.

My next step is to show the description of categories in the page only if the `user/bot` uses the links present in the sitemap to view the clicked page. i.e make the css display only if any category is loaded from sitemap's page.

I know that the link will internally call

> Category method

present inside

> Catalog controller

but not able to figure out how to pass or set any condition so that I can check for condition and change css in the  `<div class="category-description" (I want to add condition here for conditional css to make display block or none)>` of

> CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml

page while rendering

Please provide me with any details about how I can change css on

> CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml

page if the page is getting loaded from sitemap.

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="category-description" @(Request.UrlReferrer == null || !Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.Equals("/sitemap") ? Html.Raw("style=\"display: none\"") : null)>
```

(duplicated from http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/43521/clicking-on-sitemap-should-load-category-page-and-show-description-at-top.aspx)